# VC dimension for balanced binary decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

What is the VC dimension of all balanced binary decision tree of
depth $k$ in $\{0,1\}^d$? Does it depend on depth $k$ or dimension $d$?

Comment: @Aryeh thx alot, How can i proof this formula ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is shown [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguestrin/Class/10701/slides/learningtheory-bigpicture.pdf) (slide 10) that if $H_{d,k}$ is the number of depth-$k$ decision trees over $d$ input bits, then
$$v:=\log_2(H_{d,k})=
(2^k-1)(1+\log_2(d))+1
.
$$
So $v$ is an upper bound on the VC-dimension of your class. I don't know how tight it is, since you have the additional constraint of the trees being balanced.

Comment: thx alot, How can i proof this formula ?

Comment: Click on the link, the proof is in there.